# Enum Solidity Understanding

Tags: solidity

I am trying to understand solidity bit better, however the underscores drive me crazy.

Let’s say I declare an enum

```
enum wine {red, white}
```

And now I declare a variable of type enum and I assign a value

```
wine _wine = wine.red
```

Why do I need there an underscore in front of the second wine?

Happy for comments!

Comment: You would be shadowing the `wine` name otherwise. Basically you just can't name two different things with the same name otherwise the compiler cannot know which one you are referring to. You could name it anything though, not only `_enumname`.

Comment: So this means I create a variable wine of enum type _wine or is the variable name _wine?

Comment: The type comes first. So you declare a variable of enum type wine with the name `_wine`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a variable with the same name as an already existing datatype.

Example from many other typed languages:

```
// ok
string _string = "hello";

// error - cannot have a `string` type variable called `string`
string string = "hello";
```

In your case, `wine` specifies the datatype, and `_wine` is the variable name.